# Angular 5 template-driven form for creating and editing close issue (ng-bootstrap modal)

Tags: angular5, ng-bootstrap, angular-forms

I have such Angular 5 template-driven form made with ng-bootstrap modal

```
<button type="button" class="close" (click)="activeModal.close()" 
          aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
</button>

 <form (ngSubmit)="editMode ? editBoard(board) : addBoard(newBoard.value)"
          #newBoard="ngForm"
          id="newBoard"
          name="newBoard"
          novalidate>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Board name</label>
        <input type="text"
               *ngIf="editMode"
               class="form-control"
               name="name"
               #name="ngModel"
               [ngModel]="board?.name"
               (input)="changeName(board, name.value)"
               placeholder="Enter a board name (required)"
               autofocus
               required>
        <div *ngIf="name.touched && name.errors">
          <div *ngIf="name.errors.required" class="alert alert-danger">Board name is required</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

I want to use it for create and for edit. While adding and editing it's Ok but when I'm closing empty form modal (open and close) with "Close" or "x" buttons I have an error when input into field:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
```

Here is a function to open a modal

`public openBoardModalToAdd(): void {
    const ref = this.modal.open(BoardModalComponent,
      {
        keyboard: false,
        backdrop: 'static',
        size: 'lg'
      }
    );
    ref.componentInstance.board = {name: ''};
    ref.result.then(board => this.boards = [...this.boards, board]);
  }`

How I can fix this?

Comment: Use dismiss(), not close(), to close the modal with no result (i.e. to cancel the edition/creation), ass shown in every modal example of  ng-bootstrap: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Comment: thank's it works but now it's another error:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cross click or ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Undefined] if nothing in parameters

Comment: Register an error callback in then() (or use catch()), to specify what to do when the modal is dismissed.